# How to create/install a self signed certificate for Zend Server CE on Mac OS X?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I have a virtual host set up for one of my sites (http://local.mysite.com), now I want to be able to access it using SSL (https://local.mysite.com). How do I go about configuring Zend Server CE and Apache so that I can use a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about zend ... I assume that since you are using apache as the web server that the normal process should work for you...

1. Prepare key/certs (key gen, certificate request, certificate issue, certificate instal)
2. Configure Apache to use them for your zend server

See this how-to for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html